# Compute $\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\sqrt[3]{x}}{x}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I want to compute
$\displaystyle \lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\sqrt[3]{x}}{x}\right)$

- $\displaystyle \lim _{x\to 0^{+}}\left(\frac{\sqrt[3]{x}}{x}\right)$

\begin{align*}
 \lim _{x\to 0^{+}}\left(\frac{\sqrt[3]{x}}{x}\right)&= \lim _{x\to 0^{+}}\left(\frac{\sqrt[3]{x}}{\sqrt[3]{x}^{3}}\right)\\
&=\lim _{x\to 0^{+}}\left(\sqrt[3]{\frac{x}{x^3}}\right)\\
&=\lim _{x\to 0^{+}}\left(\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{x^2}}\right)\\
&=\lim _{x\to 0^{+}}\left(\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{(0^{+})^2}}\right)=+\infty\\
\lim _{x\to 0^{+}}\left(\frac{\sqrt[3]{x}}{x}\right)&=+\infty
\end{align*}

- $\displaystyle \lim _{x\to 0^{-}}\left(\frac{\sqrt[3]{x}}{x}\right)$

$x\to 0^{-}\implies x<0 \implies (-x)>0\implies (-x)^{3}>0 \implies (-x)=\sqrt[3]{(-x)^3}   $
\begin{align*}
 \lim _{x\to 0^{-}}\left(\frac{\sqrt[3]{x}}{x}\right)&=  \lim _{x\to 0^{-}}\left(\frac{-\sqrt[3]{x}}{-x}\right)\\
&=\lim _{x\to 0^{-}}\left(\frac{-\sqrt[3]{x}}{\sqrt[3]{(-x)^3}}\right)\\
\end{align*}

I'm stuck here; please correct me if am wrong
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

$$ \frac{\sqrt[3]{x}}{x} = \frac{x^{\frac13}}{x} = \frac{1}{x^{\frac23}} $$
$$\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\sqrt[3]{x}}{x}\right) = \lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{x^{\frac23}}\right) = +\infty$$

For completing your approach, let $y = -x$
$$ x < 0 \implies y > 0$$
$$\lim _{x\to 0^{-}}\left(\frac{\sqrt[3]{x}}{x}\right) = \lim_{y\to 0^{+}}\left(\frac{\sqrt[3]{-y}}{-y}\right) = \lim_{y\to 0^{+}}\left(\frac{-\sqrt[3]{y}}{-y}\right) = \lim_{y\to 0^{+}}\left(\frac{\sqrt[3]{y}}{y}\right) = +\infty  $$
$$ \therefore \lim _{x\to 0^{+}}\left(\frac{\sqrt[3]{x}}{x}\right) = \lim _{x\to 0^{-}}\left(\frac{\sqrt[3]{x}}{x}\right) =\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\sqrt[3]{x}}{x}\right)= +\infty$$

Comment: Since $\sqrt[3]{x}$ then you supposed that x is positive am I wrong

Comment: @Donfreecss You are confusing cube roots with square roots. For $\sqrt{x}$, $x$ has to be non-negative, but that isn't the case with $\sqrt[3]{x}$. Domain of $\sqrt[3]{x}$ is $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: please, do you have any reference that talk about that name of book ?

Comment: @Donfreecss Just think about it logically. The domain of $\sqrt{x}$ is $x \ge 0$ because the square of a real number is always non-negative. But the cube of a real number can be negative. For example, $(-2)^3 = -8$. The cube root of $-8$ is given by, $\sqrt[3]{-8} = -2$

Answer (score 1):

First observe that we have an indetermination (**0/0**) for:

$$\displaystyle \lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\sqrt[3]{x}}{x}\right)$$

Then, we have just to apply *L'hospital'Rule*, which is simply to take the derivative of the numerator and denominator, this is:

$$\displaystyle \lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\frac{x^{-2/3}}{3}}{x' = 1}\right) = \lim_{x \to 0} \left({\frac{x^{-2/3}}{3}}\right) = \infty$$

Comment: L'hospital is okay, but one doesn't even need this here, as one can just simplify

Comment: I know, of course.

Comment: You should write _we could_ instead of _we have_ ...